# Hiding variables in Solidity

Tags: encryption, privacy

What is the best way to encrypt and decrypt a variable in Solidity so only the msg.sender and contract can see that variable?

Answer (score 3):

Practical answer: You can't. If the contract can see it when it executes, everyone who has the blockchain can see it.

Theoretical answer that won't help you: Homomorphic encryption. See [Can smart contracts compute on encrypted data?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/can-smart-contracts-compute-on-encrypted-data)